# BCM2835 datasheet addressing system

Tags: bare-metal, assembly

I've been interested in writing a kernel for my old Raspberry Pi for quite a while, and managed to make work some ARM assembly code I found on the famous "Baking Pi" course by the University of Cambridge. Since I know some ARM assembly I wanted to dive deeper in the datasheet, but found "it contains several errors" (although I also found is an errata corrige page), and I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the following:

The first course lesson says that "the manual uses a different addressing system. An address listed as 0x7E200000 would be 0x20200000", and that would be the address of the GPIO interface.

What I don't get is: is there a correspondence between the two addresses? Can I use some sort of conversion to read from the datasheet?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

If you look at Section 1.2.3 of the same [BCM2835 Peripherals Doc](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2835/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf), it will tell you all about it.